# Crontab script not working on AWS Lightsail

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, server, cron

I have 2 crontab scripts running on my AWS Lightsail Linux server but only one of them seems to be running. The one that doesn't run is a web scraper and outputs a XLS file as final output (not sure if this affects the crontab ability, just wanted to provide some additional details). That one should run once a week on Fridays.

The one that works is an integration with Salesforce, it runs daily and has been working fine.

My code is below for the crontab scripts. Is there any limitation to crontab that could be causing the second script not to be executed? Any help is appreciated, thx!

```
57 03 * * * python3 /home/ec2-user/Applications/automated_apps/crm_automation/python-code/version_1_0.py

10 13 * * 5 python3 /home/ec2-user/Applications/automated_apps/scraper/project-files/python-code/version_1.py
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lightsail provides you EC2 instances but cheap/managed by AWS so it does not have any differences or special notices for cron jobs configuration. They still provide you a server with specific OS.

It is better or more safe if your cron expressions have output at the end of it. So you will be able to check if it's running or not and if not, what is wrong or errors happened?

```
...version_1.py >> ~/output.log 2>&1
```

Also, for `python3`, you can try to provide the full path.

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Awesome, thx. Logging the output helped me debug the issue!

Comment: Cool man, sounds good :D if it helps, can +1 for me haha